# Exclude directories from being watched in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

`--watch` is a neat feature during development. However, in my app I upload files to a directory named `tmp`. Whenever a file has been uploaded to this directory my app re-compiles which leads to all kinds of problems. I want to exclude `tmp` from being watched.

What I have tried so far is adding `tmp` to the `"exclude":` property in `tsconfig.json`, but this does not help.

I have looked at the documentation but I can't find any info on how to do this. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/configuring-watch.html

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Comment: Are these temporary files `import`ed?

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: Can you post your `tsconfig.json` and give a bit more info on your project directory structure ? e.g. where are source files, where do you store the tmp folder ,etc.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27279

Answer (score 2):

I actually have this working with the exclude on tsconfig like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "baseUrl": ".",
  },
  "exclude": ["__tests__"]
}
```

When i change any file on my `__tests__` folder it will not compile again with watch mode.

NOTE: I'm using the latest `tsc`

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft what I'm trying to achieve is not possible. [tsc -w should not recompile if a file is created into an excluded folder](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27279)