# Logs in the console stuck saying [12:06:59 PM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, nestjs

When I start the nest application, then it successfully starts and shows the logs given below.

I've used command `npm run dev:start` to start the project.

```
[11:55:17 AM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

[11:55:17 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[Nest] 23860   - 05/19/2021, 11:55:18 AM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 23860   - 05/19/2021, 11:55:18 AM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +106ms
[Nest] 23860   - 05/19/2021, 11:55:18 AM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 23860   - 05/19/2021, 11:55:18 AM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +24ms
[Nest] 23860   - 05/19/2021, 11:55:18 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/signup, POST} route +2ms
[Nest] 23860   - 05/19/2021, 11:55:18 AM   [RoutesResolver] PostController {/post}: +1ms
[Nest] 23860   - 05/19/2021, 11:55:18 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/post/create, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 23860   - 05/19/2021, 11:55:18 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/post, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 23860   - 05/19/2021, 11:55:18 AM   [RoutesResolver] CategoryController {/category}: +0ms
[Nest] 23860   - 05/19/2021, 11:55:18 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/category/create, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 23860   - 05/19/2021, 11:55:18 AM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +2ms
[Nest] 23860   - 05/19/2021, 11:55:18 AM   [bootstrap] Application started at localhost:5001
```

Now if I send any request to the end points, it successfully sends the request and data get stored in the database and also returns the data but the problem is code gets recompiled and in console it displays

```
[12:06:59 PM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
```

and it doesn't show the log messages. How can I fix this?

Comment: problably because you are writing to some file that TSC is watching. To solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59211211

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"include": [
    "src"
]
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: Doesnt work! Can you explain what this does?

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: To those who are wondering what this does, - it forces the TypeScript compiler to only consider files from the `src` folder (and all its subfolders) for the compilation. This means that the files outside of `src` (for example, the ones in the sibling `dist` folder) won't be taken into the compilation.

Answer (score 2):

If the above doesn't work, here is how i fixed the issue

This is something related with your OS (Windows 11 in my case) and ts 4.9

Try it out with typescript 4.8 instead, in the package.json include

```json
"devDependencies": {
  ...,
  "typescript": "4.8.3",
  ...
}
```

later

```
npm i
npm run start:dev
```

This might help you: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/#file-watching-changes

Comment: Tried to find root cause for 2 days and finally found this answer with 0 votes. Thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [NestJs Documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors) in **Windows** operating system for Typescript version 9+ we need to add following after **compilerOptions** in tsconfig file:

"watchOptions": {
"watchFile": "fixedPollingInterval"
}

Answer (score 0):

if the above doesn't work, here is how i fixed the issue

**for NestJS**

inside the : tsconfig.build.json file

Add   "include": ["./src"]

Looks like this

tsconfig.build.json

```
{
      "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
      "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"],
      "include": ["./src"]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know which dependency caused the issue in my case. but for me it just worked after i ran:

```
npm audit fix
```